# Difference in assigning variables inside vs outside of super block in a Ruby Thread subclass?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

If I have a class like

```
class CustomThread < Thread
  def initialize
    @outside = []
    super do
      @inside = []
    end
  end

  def push(value)
    @outside.push(value)
    @inside.push(value)
  end
end
```

What's the difference for the behavior of `@outside` vs `@inside`? How do I determine which variables to assign outside of the super block vs inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

`super` calls the same method from the parent class. So you are calling `Thread#initialize` and passing a block that assigns `@inside`. The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-c-new) tell us that this creates a new thread executing the given block.

So the difference is that `@outside` is assigned when a `CustomThread` is created, while `@inside` is assigned at some point later once the thread runs. So this is a race condition:

```
CustomThread.new.push_value 0
```

because `@inside` might not have been assigned by the time `push_value` tries to push to it. To safely use it, you would have to do

```
thread = CustomThread.new
thread.join
thread.push_value 0
```